# how can I revert to previous version of flash?

Tags: flash

The other day I applied updates and broke my ability to watch amazon videos on my computer. I am not alone. See the [amazon forum post](http://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20video%20on%20demand/ref=cm_cd_notf_thread?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx3EQAX98ED5WQ3&cdPage=1&cdThread=Tx167YET6CH0PQI).

How can I rever to the previous version of Flash?

Here's what I've tried so far. Using

```
tail -10 /var/log/dpkg.log
```

I found this line that looks like the culprit on my system:

```
2013-04-10 16:31:56 status installed flashplugin-installer:amd64 11.2.202.280ubuntu0.12.10.1
```

At this point, I'm not sure what to do. And I think the issue is complicated by the fact that the package I'm referring to is an installer, not an actual plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the fix:

1. Close running instances of your browser.
2. If you don't already have synaptic package manager installed (it isn't by default) install it. From the terminal type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install synaptic
   ```
3. You will also need to install "hal" and "hal-info", unless already installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install hal hal-info
   ```
4. Start Synaptic Package Manager
5. In the top right of the application is a search box. Search for **"flashplugin-installer"**
6. Highlight the package and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>
7. The "Force version" window should open
8. Pick version **11.2.202.243** instead of the currently installed 11.2.202.280
9. Apply changes by clicking the button that says "Apply" with a check mark under it.
10. With the package still highlighted, select from the top menu: **Package->Lock Version**
11. Close Synaptic and open a terminal
12. We need to remove old cached versions of the plugin. First type:

    ```
     cd ~/.adobe/Flash_Player
    ```
13. Next type:

    ```
     rm -rf NativeCache AssetCache APSPrivateData2
    ```
14. You can now close the terminal and reopen your browser

Thanks to [Rob S for the instructions](http://www.amazon.com/forum/amazon%20video%20on%20demand?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx3EQAX98ED5WQ3&cdMSG=addedToThread&cdPage=1&cdThread=Tx167YET6CH0PQI&newContentID=Mx3J1ILN68W9ZF7&newContentNum=15#CustomerDiscussionsNRPB) on how to do this. The above instructions are his with only slight modifications. Additionally, the last few instructions are from the [Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Amazon_Instant_Video).

Comment: When you quit synapic, it'll ask you quit and discard changes. I think that's because you've downgraded the package.

Comment: I have tested these instructions and they work for 12.10. I believe they should also work for 12.04. I haven't been able to get them to work for 13.04. For 13.04 they fail at step 6 where "force version" is disabled. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: 13.04 question here has the answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/289341/4462

Answer (score 0):

I use the `adobe-flashplugin` package instead of the `flashplugin-installer` package, so I fixed it a different way; I downloaded the old .deb file for the `adobe-flashplugin` package and installed it with `dpkg`:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/134077901/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.275-0precise1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.275-0precise1_amd64.deb
```

I'm using 12.04 (precise); you can find the appropriate download urls for other ubuntu releases by following the links here:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/adobe-flashplugin

One big drawback to doing it like this is that `apt-get` will refuse to install or update any other packages until you upgrade your `adobe-flashplugin` package back to the latest version with this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade adobe-flashplugin
```

Hopefully amazon fixes their flash player soon.