# DRM different on CentOS than Ubuntu?

Tags: flash, rpm, drm

Amazon Prime Instant Video runs on top of the Adobe Macromedia flash-plugin and works on 32bit and 64bit versions of CentOS Linux out-of-the-box.

Why does it not work on Ubuntu?
Is there a difference in Digital Rights Management between the two Ubuntu and CentOS?
Is it that Ubuntu uses a much newer kernel than 2.6.32-358.6.1?

flash-plugin 11.2.202.280
Flash can be reverted a number of ways, including manually downloading old versions from Adobe's archive.
[how can I revert to previous version of flash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280721/how-can-i-revert-to-previous-version-of-flash)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a HAL problem again as answered in the following question:
[Is there a work around to get protected Hulu or Amazon Prime instant videos working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286297/is-there-a-work-around-to-get-amazon-prime-instant-videos-working)